# Adding php fields into email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So i have a FancyForm pre-made form that has only session post name, email, and message. If i add more fields for the user to complete, how do i get what he typed into the email being sent to me from the form? Here's what i'm talking about:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                                    <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
                                    <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%"><label for="length">Telephone</label></td>
                                    <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['telephone']?>" /></td>
                                    <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                                    <td><select name="subject" id="subject">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
                                        <option value="Residential Job">Residential Job</option>
                                        <option value="Commercial Job">Commercial Job</option>
                                        <option value="Repair">Repair/Patch</option>
                                        <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
                                        <option value="Question">Question</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
                                    <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea></td>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />                              
                                    <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

The premade form had the name and email address fields already there, so they're working 100%. I added my own 'telephone' session post, but when i complete the form and email it to myself, only the name/email fields send. What am i missing?

The site: [contact form](http://www.ocalaplastering.com/contact.php)

The premade form: [fancyform](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/)

JSFiddle: [submit.php](http://jsfiddle.net/xHKFL/)

JSFiddle: [validationEngine.js](http://jsfiddle.net/rB2x8/)

Please, i'd love to get this sorted!

Thanks, Corey

This is the php i call before html on the contact.php page:

```
<?php

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];


$str='';
if($_SESSION['errStr'])
{
    $str='<div class="error">'.$_SESSION['errStr'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['errStr']);
}

$success='';
if($_SESSION['sent'])
{
    $success='<h1>Success! We will be in contact!</h1>';

    $css='<style type="text/css">#contact-form{display:none;}</style>';

    unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a php issue. Show your php code.

Comment: I added the code i call before the html tags. The rest of the PHP/JS is in the JSFiddles above. Hopefully that helps. If you need more, let me know specifically what i can get you and i'll do that immediately.

Comment: Simply by adding the new post session ids into the submit.php form i was able to solve this. Quite simple actually.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding the new post session ids into the submit.php form i was able to solve this. Quite simple actually.